# How do get the entrypoint in a webpack rule

Tags: webpack

I have a webpack config with entrypoints.

I need to make a condition based on the entrypoint. The easiest way I can think of is like this. But I don't know how to get the entrypoint in the rules. I've read about layers but I don't know exactly how that would work here.

```
const entry = (env) => {
  const entrypoints = {
    app: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'index.js')],
    careers: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'careers.js')],
    ckeditor:[path.resolve(__dirname, 'careers.js')],
  }
  return entrypoints;
};

module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
              config: {
                ctx: {
                  entry: <entrypoint???>
                },
              },
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

I tried like this

```
const entrypoints = {
    app: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'index.js')],
    careers: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'careers.js')],
    ckeditor: {
        import: path.resolve(__dirname, 'careers.js'),
        layer: 'ckeditor',
    },
  }
..
module.exports = {
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'postcss-loader',
              options: {
                config: {
                  ctx: {
                    entry: layer
                  },
                },
```